# How to get region properties from image that is already labeled in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation, connected-components, labeling

I am labeling images using the watershed algorithm in OpenCV (similar to this tutorial: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html) such that at the end I obtain an array of labels where each region has an integer value corresponding to its label. Now, I want to obtain the coordinates of the bounding boxes and areas of each region.

I know this is easily done with `skimage.measure.regionprops()` but for considerations of speed of execution I would like to achieve this without importing skimage, ideally directly with OpenCV.

I have tried using `cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats()` but it only seems to work if the image is binary not if the labels are already defined.

I have tried to binarize the labeled image and then relabel it with `connectedComponentsWithStats()` as follows (note that the background has a label of 1 in this case and I want to remove it):

```py
segmented = cv2.watershed(image.astype('uint8'), markers)

segmented_bin = segmented.copy()
segmented_bin[segmented < 2] = 0
segmented_bin[segmented > 1] = 255
num_labels, label_image, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(segmented_bin.astype('uint8'), 4, cv2.CV_32S)
```

But this approach merges regions that are not separated by background which is not the desired effect.

Essentially I would like to know if there is a function similar to `connectedComponentsWithStats()` that deals with already labeled images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody else is interested, I ended up reverting to `skimage.measure.regionprops()` since I could not get `cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats()`. The time overhead is only in the tens of millisecond per image.

Answer (score 3):

Since (if I'm not mistaken) each label represents a continuous area, we can just iterate over all the non-background labels.

```
for i in range(2, marker_count + 1):
```

For each label, we can create a corresponding binary mask (pixels with that label become 255, everything else becomes a 0) using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
    mask = np.where(segmented==i, np.uint8(255), np.uint8(0))
```

Since [`cv2.boundingRect`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga103fcbda2f540f3ef1c042d6a9b35ac7) can process single-channel images as well, we can use it to determine the bounding box directly from the mask.

```
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(mask)
```

The area of the label is simply the count of the pixels with given label (i.e. all non-zero pixels in the mask). We can simply use [`cv2.countNonZero`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaa4b89393263bb4d604e0fe5986723914) for that. Since we already know the bounding box, we can save some work by processing only the corresponding ROI.

```
    area = cv2.countNonZero(mask[y:y+h,x:x+w])
```

And we're done.

```
    print "Label %d at (%d, %d) size (%d x %d) area %d pixels" % (i,x,y,w,h,area)
```

---

**Console output**

```
Label 2 at (41, 14) size (47 x 49) area 1747 pixels
Label 3 at (111, 30) size (48 x 47) area 1719 pixels
Label 4 at (71, 51) size (56 x 48) area 1716 pixels
Label 5 at (152, 61) size (48 x 47) area 1676 pixels
Label 6 at (25, 75) size (47 x 48) area 1719 pixels
Label 7 at (109, 76) size (49 x 49) area 1748 pixels
Label 8 at (192, 82) size (49 x 48) area 1774 pixels
Label 9 at (64, 97) size (48 x 49) area 1695 pixels
Label 10 at (1, 114) size (47 x 48) area 1720 pixels
Label 11 at (139, 114) size (52 x 48) area 1727 pixels
Label 12 at (97, 132) size (48 x 48) area 1745 pixels
Label 13 at (181, 133) size (48 x 47) area 1667 pixels
Label 14 at (41, 140) size (47 x 48) area 1733 pixels
Label 15 at (129, 167) size (45 x 47) area 1666 pixels
Label 16 at (5, 169) size (50 x 48) area 1713 pixels
Label 17 at (72, 176) size (46 x 48) area 1745 pixels
Label 18 at (171, 177) size (50 x 49) area 1772 pixels
Label 19 at (35, 205) size (46 x 47) area 1702 pixels
Label 20 at (106, 207) size (55 x 49) area 1909 pixels
Label 21 at (155, 219) size (43 x 47) area 1537 pixels
Label 22 at (65, 237) size (51 x 48) area 1713 pixels
Label 23 at (25, 251) size (50 x 49) area 1818 pixels
Label 24 at (108, 264) size (48 x 47) area 1730 pixels
Label 25 at (155, 264) size (46 x 47) area 1711 pixels
```

---

**Images**

- Input
  [image: Input image]
- Colored labels
  [image: Colored labels]
- Labeled bounding boxes
  [image: Labeled bounding boxes]

---

**The complete script**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# START of original watershed example
# from https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html

img = cv2.imread('water_coins.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# noise removal
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel, iterations = 2)
# sure background area
sure_bg = cv2.dilate(opening,kernel,iterations=3)
# Finding sure foreground area
dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(opening,cv2.DIST_L2,5)
ret, sure_fg = cv2.threshold(dist_transform,0.7*dist_transform.max(),255,0)
# Finding unknown region
sure_fg = np.uint8(sure_fg)
unknown = cv2.subtract(sure_bg,sure_fg)

# Marker labelling
marker_count, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(sure_fg)
# Add one to all labels so that sure background is not 0, but 1
markers = markers+1
# Now, mark the region of unknown with zero
markers[unknown==255] = 0

segmented = cv2.watershed(img,markers)

# END of original watershed example

output = np.zeros_like(img)
output2 = img.copy()

# Iterate over all non-background labels
for i in range(2, marker_count + 1):
    mask = np.where(segmented==i, np.uint8(255), np.uint8(0))
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(mask)
    area = cv2.countNonZero(mask[y:y+h,x:x+w])
    print "Label %d at (%d, %d) size (%d x %d) area %d pixels" % (i,x,y,w,h,area)

    # Visualize
    color = np.uint8(np.random.random_integers(0, 255, 3)).tolist()
    output[mask!=0] = color
    cv2.rectangle(output2, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), color, 1)
    cv2.putText(output2,'%d'%i,(x+w/4, y+h/2), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, color, 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imwrite('wshseg_colors.png', output)
cv2.imwrite('wshseg_boxes.png', output2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this approach does work to give the result I want. However, it is really slow. To process a 2100x4288 image with _ca._ 150 regions, this method takes about 1.8s _versus_ 52ms for the `connectedComponentsWithStats()` code. I was wondering if there is a way to get a similar speed to the latter.

Comment: @DougP. Can you attach a sample image that you're using? Does the timing include the visualization/printing?

Comment: @DougP 2 ideas: For large images with relatively small blobs, it might be faster to use the coordinates of all non-white pixels, rather than a mask. (Basically `np.where(segmented==i` and then `np.dstack` the the two arrays it returns to make something `cv2.boundingRect` can use.) | Other idea is to use contours+hierarchy on inverted version of your `segmented_bin`. That seems to pick up all the discrete bits. Not really sure yet why `connectedComponents` clupms them all together.

Comment: Thank you for the brainstorming. The timing only refers to the properties gathering, neither segmentation nor visualization are included. I will be trying contours on segmented_bin although I don't understand either why `connectedComponents` bundles the regions. There is a 1-pixel wide separation boundary between regions in `segmented` (-1 set by the watershed algorithm) and it is still there (as 0, background) in `segmented_bin` but `connectedComponents` clumps them all together in the coin example regardless of the connectivity (4 or 8) selected.